# Can´t select with two different alias into same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do a select like this:

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM ##TTC AS TT 
     WHERE (TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP') TTIEPSCUOTA ON 
C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPSCUOTA.VOUCHER 
AND C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXITEMGROUP
AND PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPSCUOTA.SOURCERECID
```

Problem is I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'TTIEPSCUOTA '

And that´s because in SQL we can´t use ALIASES after WHERE clause, can someone explain me how can I refactor this query to use  `TTIEPSCUOTA` after where clause? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unbalanced parentheses:

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
(SELECT *
 FROM ##TTC TT
 WHERE TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP'
) TTIEPSCUOTA
ON C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPSCUOTA.VOUCHER AND
   C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXITEMGROUP AND
   PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPSCUOTA.SOURCERECID
```

Note:  You should not be specifying the algorithm for the `JOIN` unless you know that it is necessary.

Edit:

Why are you using a subquery anyway?  This is more simply written as:

```
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
##TTC TTIEPSCUOTA
ON C1.TT_VOUCHER = TTIEPSCUOTA.VOUCHER AND
   C1.TT_TAXITEMGROUP = TTIEPSCUOTA.TAXITEMGROUP AND
   PRO.TTF_SOURCERECID = TTIEPSCUOTA.SOURCERECID AND
   TT.TAXCODE LIKE 'IEPSCUOTAP'
```

Comment: I just keep getting same issue `Incorrect syntax near 'TTIEPSCUOTA '.`

Comment: Presumably, this is part of a larger query.  It is not obvious why a well-formed query with this snipper would pose a problem.

Comment: we get same result as your second query? just dropping subquery?

Comment: @Benny . . . They version with and without the subquery are functionally the same.